# Strongloop slc clt error: failed with error: read ETIMEDOUT

Tags: strongloop

I have a strongloop-pm service running on a remote box.  Anytime I try to send commands to that service using "slc ctl IPADDRESS" or "slc deploy IPADDRESS" or any other slc command I get an error that says command "failed with Error: read ETIMEDOUT"

For example here are a couple commands that I have tried:

```
slc ctl -C http://IPADDRESS:8701
Command "status" on "http://IPADDRESS:8701" failed with Error: read ETIMEDOUT
```

and:

```
slc deploy http://IPADDRESS deploy
Error connecting to server: { [Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }
```

the output of the logs (located at /var/log/upstart/strong-pm.log) on the remote box look like this:

```
~
~
(END)
2015-12-29T05:39:04.407Z pid:24858 worker:16     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:327:15)
2015-12-29T05:39:04.407Z pid:24858 worker:16     at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
2015-12-29T05:39:04.407Z pid:24858 worker:16     at Module.require (module.js:355:17)
2015-12-29T05:39:04.407Z pid:24858 worker:16     at Module.module.__proto__.require (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/strong-pm/node_modules/strong-agent/lib/agent.js:185:42)
2015-12-29T05:39:04.407Z pid:24858 worker:16     at require (internal/module.js:13:17)
2015-12-29T05:39:04.407Z pid:24858 worker:16     at PassportConfigurator.configureProvider (/var/lib/strong-pm/svc/2/work/291d15592019de52965662c23a2d101cd3887d49.1450903558289/node_modules/loopback-component-passport/lib/passport-configurator.js:149:22)
2015-12-29T05:39:04.407Z pid:24858 worker:16     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/strong-pm/svc/2/work/291d15592019de52965662c23a2d101cd3887d49.1450903558289/server/server.js:80:24)
2015-12-29T05:39:04.407Z pid:24858 worker:16     at Module._compile (module.js:399:26)
2015-12-29T05:39:04.407Z pid:24858 worker:16     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:406:10)
2015-12-29T05:39:04.407Z pid:24858 worker:16     at Module.load (module.js:345:32)
2015-12-29T05:39:04.414Z pid:24581 worker:0 ERROR supervisor worker id 16 (pid 24858) accidental exit with 1
2015-12-29T05:39:04.682Z pid:24880 worker:17 INFO strong-agent native addon missing, install a compiler
2015-12-29T05:39:04.683Z pid:24880 worker:17 INFO strong-agent v2.0.2 profiling app 'placesAPI' pid '24880'
2015-12-29T05:39:04.688Z pid:24880 worker:17 INFO strong-agent[24880] started profiling agent
2015-12-29T05:39:06.643Z pid:24581 worker:0 INFO supervisor started worker 18 (pid 24898)
2015-12-29T05:39:06.643Z pid:24581 worker:0 INFO supervisor resized to 2
2015-12-29T05:39:06.790Z pid:24880 worker:17 module.js:329
2015-12-29T05:39:06.790Z pid:24880 worker:17     throw err;
2015-12-29T05:39:06.790Z pid:24880 worker:17     ^
2015-12-29T05:39:06.791Z pid:24880 worker:17 Error: Cannot find module 'passport-local'
2015-12-29T05:39:06.791Z pid:24880 worker:17     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:327:15)
2015-12-29T05:39:06.791Z pid:24880 worker:17     at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
2015-12-29T05:39:06.791Z pid:24880 worker:17     at Module.require (module.js:355:17)
2015-12-29T05:39:06.791Z pid:24880 worker:17     at Module.module.__proto__.require (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/strong-pm/node_modules/strong-agent/lib/agent.js:185:42)
2015-12-29T05:39:06.791Z pid:24880 worker:17     at require (internal/module.js:13:17)
~
~
(END)
```

Incase it helps-- a scan of the open ports on my box looks like this:

```
 ✘ peter@peters-MacBook-Pro  ~/Desktop/projects/www/places-api   master ●  nmap -P0 IPADDRESS

Starting Nmap 7.00 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2015-12-29 01:34 EST
Nmap scan report for IPADDRESS
Host is up (0.085s latency).
Not shown: 989 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
21/tcp   open   ftp
22/tcp   open   ssh
25/tcp   closed smtp
80/tcp   closed http
443/tcp  closed https
554/tcp  open   rtsp
3000/tcp closed ppp
3001/tcp closed nessus
4444/tcp closed krb524
7070/tcp open   realserver
8701/tcp open   unknown
```

Comment: Is your remote server behind a firewall? If this is on aws you'll need to open the port on the security group assigned to the instance, for example.

Comment: hey thanks for taking a look. The app is hosted on a digital ocean ubuntu instance.  I disabled the firewall when I encountered this problem but it didn't help.

Comment: @RyanGraham I added the output of the strong-pm.log file on the remote box.  It looks like some dependencies might not be getting installed?

Comment: The missing dependency is a problem with your app, but I don't think that should be stopping `slc ctl` from working. There is a lot missing from the log output, so it is hard to tell what else is happening from it. Note that upstart will be rotating the logs for you, so the logs are likely being spread across multiple files.